# Streaming Radio

Tags: banshee, proxy, streaming, hostname

I can stream Radio Paradise in Audacious but not in Banshee. Also in Banshee, when I try to access Amazon, I get this message:
Unable to load page

Problem occurred while loading the URL https://one.ubuntu.com/music/store/amz/geo/home/

Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/170162/banshee-wont-connect-to-amazon-mp3-store `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy` or `System Settings > Network > Network proxy > Method=None (Apply system wide)` should work

Answer (score 0):

Please report the first problem in bugzilla.gnome.org and report the second problem in launchpad.