# Banshee won't connect to Amazon mp3 store

Tags: banshee

Banshee has stopped connecting to the amazon mp3 store. It used to work fine but now I get the following error message from Banshee:

```
Unable to load page
Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()
```

This problem occurred while loading the URL https://one.ubuntu.com/music/store/amz/UK/home/

I'm running Banshee 2.4.1 and 12.04LTS. My internet connection is fine (I'm using it to post this). Amazon say there's nothing wrong with their server - it seems to be me...Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and run `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy` if are you not using a proxy to connect to the web.

If you do need to use a proxy, it appears there is an issue with one of the proxy settings. Fix it and everything should work again.

Comment: Cheers! That worked :-) I've never knowingly connected through a proxy so why something changed in that respect I don't know.

Comment: Fantastic! Fixed for me. It's not just Banshee that breaks. If you are not using a proxy, you can probably fix this by `System Settings > Network > Network proxy > Method=None (Apply system wide)`